# change text of radio button to html

Tags: javascript, radio-button

i would like to change the text of the radio button into one that has additional html tags using javascript. e.g `test` into `<a href=#>test</a>`. Is this possible?

This is the html

```
<div class="form-row form-row-wide" id="gift-cards_field">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select a gift card</legend>
      <label><input type="radio" name="gift-cards" value="NN001"> NN001</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="gift-cards" value="NN002"> NN002</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="gift-cards" value="NN003"> NN003</label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

This is the current javascript that i have written which does not work..

```
var giftcard = document.getElementsByName("gift-cards");
if(giftcard[0].value === 'NN001'){
    giftcard[0].nextSibling.data = '<a href="#">NN001<img rc="https://www.google.com.sg/logos/doodles/2014/perseid-meteor-shower-2014-6280300325765120-res.png" /></a>'
};
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2nw8tLy6/1/)

Comment: You have to end your line with `;`

Comment: thanks. i tried adding ; but it still does not work.

also added link to jsfiddle

Comment: The JSFiddle you added seems to have nothing to do with this..

Comment: sorry. updated the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do that

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[name="gift-cards"]')).forEach(function(item) {
    var wrap  = document.createElement('a'),
        node  = item.nextSibling;

    wrap.href = '#';
    item.parentNode.appendChild(wrap)
    wrap.appendChild(node);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/31cvsvv7/1/)

Trying to follow your rather strange example, it would be something like

```
var item = document.querySelector('[name="gift-cards"][value="NN001"]'),
    wrap = document.createElement('a'),
    img  = document.createElement('img'),
    node = item.nextSibling;

wrap.href = '#';
img.src   = 'https://www.google.com.sg/logos/doodles/2014/perseid-meteor-shower-2014-6280300325765120-res.png';

item.parentNode.appendChild(wrap)
wrap.appendChild(node);
wrap.appendChild(img);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/31cvsvv7/2/)

Comment: I just thought the `giftcard[0].nextSibling.data` line was somewhat strange, no worries.

Comment: Just wondering as i am still learning, what exactly does 'node = item.nextSibling;' means?

Comment: We're targeting the elements with a name, so to get the next sibling, the textNode, we have to use nextSibling, and `item` is the elements, it's from the argument in `forEach`

Comment: i see. noted. pardon me if i ask another question. what should i do if i do not want to add the <a href=#> anymore but only add the <img> tag. I can't seem to modify the code to work properly in this scenario.

Comment: If you don't want the anchor, it's a lot easier, all you have to do is append the image, like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/31cvsvv7/3/**